# onUpdate method not working in react-custom-scrollbars

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using "react-custom-scrollbars" in my React.js application. I want to call a method whenever a user scrolls. I am trying onUdpate method for this.

```
<div className="thumbs-panel">
    <Scrollbars ref="scrollbars" onUpdate={this.handleUpdate.bind(this)}>
        <table className="scrollcontent" id="scrollcontent">
            <div className="thumbs-flex barc-thumb-flex">
                {this.state.sub_sprite && this.state.sub_sprite.map((sprite,j)=>(
                sixty_array.map((item,i)=>{
                return <div className={`thumb ${((this.state.thumb_active_from === ((sprite.time * 60) + (i+1))))||((this.state.thumb_active_from <= ((sprite.time * 60) + (i+1))) && (((sprite.time * 60) + (i+1)) <= this.state.thumb_active_to )) ? "active":""}`}>
                <div className="thumb-inner" onClick={this.selectThumb.bind(this, (sprite.time * 60) + (i+1))}>
                    <div className="image" style={{backgroundImage: `url('${sprite.url}')`, backgroundPositionX: -((i % 10) *100) + "px", backgroundPositionY: -(82 * Math.floor(i/10))}}></div>
                <div className="timestamp">{this.secondsToHms((sprite.time * 60) + (i+1))}</div>
            </div>
</div>
})
))}

</div>
</table>
</Scrollbars>
</div>
```

and this us my onUpdate method

```
handleUpdate(values){
        console.log("update called")
}
```

handleUpdate method is never getting called on scroll. I tried onScroll method too, but that is also not working. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the listener in `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount(){
    document.querySelector('/*Selector of your scrolling element*/').addEventListener('scroll', this.handleUpdate);
```